# I am trying to extract data from one file into string and coping it into another file from that string

Tags: assembly

The codes below shows that i want to open an existing file and copy its data one by one in my string and save that data from string to another file but for some reason it is just saving the first character of my file as many times as much as the size of file. Can someone help me in that.

```
.model small

.stack 100h

.data

file        db 'file.txt',0

file1       db 'file1.txt',0

buffer      db ?                ;data buffer

buffer1     db ?

handle      dw ? 

handle2     dw ?

mystring    db 37

.code

main:

;Housekeeping section

mov ax,@data        ;establish addressability

mov ds,ax           ;to data segment

;Main Process Section

xor ax,ax

xor bx,bx

xor cx,cx

xor dx,dx

call openfile

mov dx,offset file

int 21h

mov handle, ax

call createfile

mov dx,offset file1

int 21h

jc error                ;end program if error

mov handle2,ax          ;save file handle 

 lea  si, mystring       ;SI POINTS TO A STRING.  <======================

reading:

;READ ONE BYTE.

    mov ah, 3FH             ;read from the file

    mov bx, handle          ;normal file

    mov cx, 1               ;HOW MANY BYTES TO READ.

    mov dx, offset buffer   ;THE BYTE WILL BE STORED HERE.

    int 21h                 ;NUMBER OF BYTES READ RETURNS IN AX.

;CHECK EOF (END OF FILE).

    cmp ax,0                ;IF AX == 0 THEN EOF.

    je  eofp

;SAVE BYTE IN STRING.                               <======================

    mov  al, buffer         ;AL = BYTE READ.

    mov  [ si ], al         ;SAVE BYTE IN CURRENT POSITION.



;WRITE BYTE TO THE SECOND FILE.           

    mov ah, 40h                            ; write to 

    mov bx, handle2                        ; file handle

    mov dx, offset mystring                ; where to find data to write

    mov cx, 1                              ;LENGTH OF STRING IN CX.

    int 21h

    inc  si                 ;MOVE POINTER TO NEXT POSITION.

    jmp reading                            ;REPEAT PROCESS.
eofp:


error:

mov ax, 4c00h

int 21h

proc createfile

;creating a file

mov ah,3ch

xor cx,cx

ret

createfile endp

proc openfile

;open file 

mov ah,3Dh

mov al,0            ;read mode    

ret

openfile endp


end main
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is that you increment `si`, the pointer to where you are storing the next byte read. But when you write the byte to file, you are telling the handler to take the byte from `mystring`, where `si` was originally pointing to.

The result is that the first byte value is written to file every time, and on subsequent file reads the bytes are written across the data segment, but ignored.

It would have been easier to dispense with `mystring` and `si` and simply read each byte into `buffer` and write each byte from there too. `mystring` overflows after 37 bytes even if you correct the error by replacing `mov dx, offset mystring` with `mov dx, si`.

```
reading:
    ;READ ONE BYTE.
    mov ah, 3FH             ;read from the file
    mov bx, handle          ;normal file
    mov cx, 1               ;HOW MANY BYTES TO READ.
    mov dx, offset buffer   ;THE BYTE WILL BE STORED HERE.
    int 21h                 ;NUMBER OF BYTES READ RETURNS IN AX.

    ;CHECK EOF (END OF FILE).
    cmp ax,0                ;IF AX == 0 THEN EOF.
    je  eofp

    ;WRITE BYTE TO THE SECOND FILE.
    mov ah, 40h             ;write to
    mov bx, handle2         ;file handle
    mov dx, offset buffer   ;where to find data to write
    mov cx, 1               ;LENGTH OF STRING IN CX.
    int 21h
    jmp reading             ;REPEAT PROCESS.
eofp:
```

Incidentally, you don't check the `carry` after making the call to open the source file with int `21h` function`3Dh`.